# Multimap not sorting

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, multimap

I have this multimap built to map the hamming distance of a string to its corresponding string.

Since the hamming distance of two strings could be the same, I want them to be sorted in ascending order. However when I print it out, it is not sorted. The hamdistArray is declared as an unsigned type.

```
typedef multimap<unsigned, string, less<unsigned> > Check;
            Check pairs; 

            pairs.insert(Check::value_type(hamdistArray[j], d.sortedWordDatabase[j]));

            for(Check::const_iterator iter = pairs.begin(); iter != pairs.end(); ++iter)
            {
                cout << iter->first << '\t' << iter->second<< endl;
            }
```

Comment: `Check` is a silly name for this type.

Comment: I don't see how your posted code is a testcase, as you only insert one value.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal The code is inside a for loop, hence the 'j'. Check was chosen because it corrects a string based on how close its hamming distance is from a database.

Comment: Then please include the loop in your testcase. `Check` is a silly name: the type does not correct anything; it's a type, not a procedure. It is the name of a type of data storage, not an algorithm that mutates data.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: I appreciate your insight. It might not make sense to you the name that I have chosen for this type. I hope it will not hinder your ability to help me answer my question though. :)

Answer (score 6):

Elements in a multimap are sorted by the key (in this case the unsigned hamming distance). Elements with the same key are not sorted by the value (in this case the string), they are usually kept in the order in which they were inserted.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. How would I sort the hamming distance together with its corresponding string then? Should I just do it manually?

Comment: Use set or multiset of pair of unsigned and string.

Comment: The multimap docs seem to back up this answer: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/multimap/insert/

Answer (score 0):

The less template function is not necessary since it's the default. Try declaring Check without as:

```
typedef multimap<unsigned, string> Check;
```

Edited: The best way to do this is to generate a hash-key as the *key_type* and than the *value-type* could be a `std::pair<unsigned, string>`

Comment: How is this going to change anything?

Comment: Tried it but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using `std::multimap`, because when keys are compared, it is not known which value they represent.

Answer (score 0):

`multimap` only sorts by its key (length) not also by value (string). In this case I suspect your best approach is a `std::map<unsigned, std::set<std::string> >`. You could also use a `std::set<std::pair<unsigned, std::string> >` but searching would require you to construct dummy `pair`s to search on.